# onchange and focus out event on a text box with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/or0db22d/

I want to show that div error if the textbox content's length greater than 3 then show that div with error as wrong format

and when textbox is not getting entered or out of focus , div error should go out

HTML

```
<div id="errorholder">
</div>
<br />
<input id="txtbox" type="text">
```

JS

```
$('#txtbox').onchange(function(e) 
{
if($(this).length >3)
$('#errorholder').text("wrong format");

});

$('#txtbox').focusout(function(e) 
{
$('#errorholder').text("");

});
```

how  to write these two function ?

Comment: I think you want to use `$.on('change')`, `$(this).val().length` and `$.on('focusout')` https://jsfiddle.net/or0db22d/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('#txtbox').on('input', function(e) {
  if ($(this).val().length > 3)
    $('#errorholder').text("wrong format");
  else
    $('#errorholder').text("");
});

//$('#txtbox').focusout(function(e) {
//  $('#errorholder').text("");

//});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="errorholder">
</div>
<br />
<input id="txtbox" type="text">
```

1. Use `on input` event
2. get the input value using `.val()`

Answer (score 0):

Change our JS code to

```
$('input').on('keyup',function(){
      if($(this).val().length > 3)
      $('#errorholder').text("wrong format");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You have to use keyup event. Change event will listen only you focus out on text box. To find the length of text box you have to use $(this).val().length

```
$('#txtbox').keyup(function(e) 
{
  if($(this).val().length >3){
    $('#errorholder').text("wrong format");
  }
});

$('#txtbox').focusout(function(e) 
{
$('#errorholder').text("");

});
```

here updated jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/or0db22d/4/